# iOS Piano sheet to NSString representation with alphabets (A-Z)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am making a game similar to piano tile "[Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/piano-tiles-dont-tap-white/id848160327?mt=8)".

I have 26 mp3 files representing notes in ascending order (A.mp3 - Z.mp3)

Now I need to convert piano sheet or any other standard representation (e.g. MIDI) to a string of upper case alphabets.

The duration or volume of each note does not matter. I just need a consecutive sequence of characters for each song.

If a note in its original format is too low/high, I simply replace it with the lowest('A')/highest('Z'.mp3) sound.

I store the current "noteIndex" and "songIndex" in the `NSUserDefault`. When the user tap on the correct piano key, I will call `+playNextNote` which increment "noteIndex" and/or "songIndex" accordingly and call `+playSong:(int)song note:(int)note`.

**EDIT:**

When I search online, most piano pieces are in PDF sheet or MIDI.

**EDIT 2:**

Detailed implementation

The format I want is in the `+ (NSArray *)songList` method

```
+ (void)playNote:(char)note {
    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c.mp3", note];

    [ResourceHelper playFx:file];
}

+ (void)playRandomNote {

    [ResourceHelper playNote:[Helper getRandomIntBothInclusiveLow:'A' high:'Z']];

}

+ (void)playFx:(NSString *)fx {
    [ModuleHelper playFx:fx];
}



#define KEY_SONG_TITLE @"KEY_SONG_TITLE"
#define KEY_SONG_NOTES @"KEY_SONG_NOTES"



+ (void)playNextNote {

    int songIndex = [CacheHelper songIndex];
    int noteIndex = [CacheHelper noteIndex];

    NSDictionary *song = [ResourceHelper songList][songIndex - 1];
    NSString *notes = song[KEY_SONG_NOTES];
    int numChars = notes.length;
    if (noteIndex < numChars - 1) {
        noteIndex++;
    }
    else {
        int numSongs = [ResourceHelper songList].count;
        if (songIndex < numSongs - 1) {
            songIndex++;
            noteIndex = 0;
        }
        else {
            songIndex = 1;//0th song is random song
            noteIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    [ResourceHelper playNoteWithSongIndex:songIndex noteIndex:noteIndex];

}

+ (void)playNoteWithSongIndex:(int)songIndex noteIndex:(int)noteIndex {

    NSDictionary *song = [ResourceHelper songList][songIndex - 1];
    NSString *notes = song[KEY_SONG_NOTES];

    char note = [notes characterAtIndex:noteIndex];
    [ResourceHelper playNote:note];

}


+ (NSString *)songNameWithIndex:(int)index {
    if (index == 0) {
        return LOCALIZE(STR_UI_RANDOM_NOTES);
    }
    else {
        NSDictionary *song = [ResourceHelper songList][index - 1];
        return song[KEY_SONG_TITLE];
    }
}

static NSArray *songList;
+ (NSArray *)songList {
    if (songList == nil) {
        songList = @[
             @{KEY_SONG_TITLE:@"Baby",
               KEY_SONG_NOTES:@"AABBCC"},

             @{KEY_SONG_TITLE:@"Just Give Me a Reason",
               KEY_SONG_NOTES:@"AAABBBCCC"},

             @{KEY_SONG_TITLE:@"When You Believe",
               KEY_SONG_NOTES:@"ABCABCABC"},

             @{KEY_SONG_TITLE:@"Firework",
               KEY_SONG_NOTES:@"CCCCBBBBAAAA"},

             ];
    }
    return songList;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your question. Could you show the initial format (pdf?) and then the one you want?

Comment: http://www.zhaogepu.com/jianpu/260342.html

Comment: @Larme the website is in chinese but you can view the sheet (image). What I want is text based notation (any format will do since I can parse it accordingly, but it has to be in text)